# jQuery $.Get load specific class from target page

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to load a via ajax a specific div class from a target url. When using the `.load()` function, it loads fine.

```
$( "#container" ).load( "mydomain.com/testpage.html .product_container" );
```

But when I use the `$.Get` function, it doesn't return the appropriate class.

```
$.get('mydomain.com/testpage.html .product_container', function(data){
    $('#container').append(data);
});
```

In fact nothing happens. My question is, is it possible with the `$.Get` function to load a specific div class from the target URL?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

It seems that including a parent ID div works with the `$.Get` function.

```
$.get('mydomain.com/testpage.html #top_container .product_container', function(data){
    $('#container').append(data);
});
```

But the problem with this is that it also includes whatever else #top_container includes so that's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
$.get('mydomain.com/testpage.html', function(data){
    var content = $(data).find('.product_container');
    $('#container').append(content);
});
```

Comment: Just tried this. It does load the contents of .product_container but it doesn't include the outer div. So instead of one main div with class product_container appended to #container. I have all of the nested divs of product_container appended to #container

Comment: Oh actually this works. 

    var content = $(data).find('.product_container');